# how to disable a button in jquery

Tags: jquery, button, disabled-input

```
   <a href="<?php print $base_url ?>/node/<?php print $part;?>/take"  id="take_quiz1" >
<button  class="btn btn-white btn-cons btn-cancel"  >Take quiz test</button>
</a>
```

Here i am using both anchor tag and button tag.How to disable this menu in jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery disable all button of a css class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769223/jquery-disable-all-button-of-a-css-class)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(".btn-cancel").prop("disabled",true);
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/wWRx6/

IF link also u have to disable http://jsfiddle.net/wWRx6/2/

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="take_quiz1" >
<button  class="btn btn-white btn-cons btn-cancel"  >Take quiz test</button>
</a>
```

Comment: @ChrisBrown Because `.prop()` only handles properties but not values, while `.attr()` handles values of the properties. Using `.attr()` on boolean properties (without any values required, actually) may cause conflicting behavior. Plus, you cannot simply set `.attr('disabled', false)`. You can read the documentation on `.prop()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @ChrisBrown for a structured answer, check this [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/1671639)

Comment: @pratik Josshi but the link still workin..it doesn't get disable

Comment: @PratikJoshi i want to disable the button...and the link should not go to anywhere

Comment: Then u use PHP to set this , 
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="take_quiz1" >
<button  class="btn btn-white btn-cons btn-cancel"  >Take quiz test</button>
</a>

Comment: If i click the button,it goes directly to the link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50963/discussion-between-dhivya-and-pratik-joshi)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [**prop**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to update `disabled` attribute

```
$('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
```

To disable link you can use `preventDefault()` method

```
$('#take_quiz1').click(function(e) {
    // Update the flag to true/false as per your requirements 
    if(flag){ 
     e.preventDefault();
    } 
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You disable a button by:

```
$('button').attr('disabled','');
```

You add `disabled` attribute to the button

You do that by [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

Comment: Nope, very bad idea using `.attr()` for boolean attributes.

Comment: @Terry, disabled attrubute accepts disabled as value

Answer (score 0):

try this it should help you

```
 $(".btn-cons").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

here is live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/wWRx6/1/

Comment: PSA: Do not use `.attr()` for boolean attributes. It's a bad idea!

Comment: @Terry, first of all a boolean isn't a valid value for disabled.

Comment: No, boolean attributes are called boolean because it's their **presence or absence**, not their declared values), that dictates a certain behavior. [Refer to the docs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#boolean-attributes).

Comment: @Terry i edited my answer with js fiddle it and its work fine then what is the problem ?

Comment: @SmartKiller It works, but that is not good practice. So is using `<b>` or `<center>` in modern browsers. They work, perfectly fine, but not the right way to get stuff done.