# How to find a spesific class,and find a spesific element and add disabled attr to it

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons, one that votes no and one that votes yes, i need to disable both buttons after user have clicked.
I also want to add the color: grey to the button clicked.

So far im able to disable the one clicked but not the other one.

**My code so far are:**

The html code: (also runs in a loop, so there is increment on the id)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" data-id="yes" data-problem_id="1" class="problem_vote">
            <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">YES</button>
        </a>
    </div>  
    <div class="btn-group"> 
        <a href="#" data-id="no" data-problem_id="2" class="problem_vote">
             <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">NO</button>
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I have this jQuery code so far:

```
$('.problem_vote').on('click touchstart', function(e){

 e.preventDefault();
 var link = this;

 $(link).prev('.btn-group-justified').find('a').attr('disabled','disabled');
 $(link).find('button').css('background-color','grey');

});
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion, instead of adding a grey background style, add a class which can later be freely modified. It might seem like a silly change, but if I had a dollar for every time a framework came under my eyes that didn't do this and therefore was horrible to adjust, I would be much less worried about money ;) Keeping style/layout and functionality consistently separate will save you or others a lot of trouble somewhere on the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery disable all button of a css class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769223/jquery-disable-all-button-of-a-css-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable both at once, do this:

```
$('.problem_vote').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find("button").css('background-color', 'grey');
    $(this).closest(".btn-group-justified").find("a").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: The page have alot of elements with that class, so i need to adapt the code to the elements clicked. think of the html code inside a foreach

Comment: the code makes the both of the buttons are grey..maybe smal fix? rest seam to work

Comment: it adds disabled, but the colors dont show on the button clicked, its inside the a tag.

Comment: @sdf Oh, though it also was the problem. Edited again.

Comment: $(this).css('background-color', 'grey');  cos the this element is the a href, i need to set the color to the button inside the a.

Comment: @sdf Oy. Edited again :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button.btn-vote').click(function() {
  var action = $(this).parent().data('id');
  var tmp = $(this).parents('div.btn-group-justified')[0]
  $(tmp).find('button').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).css('background-color', 'grey');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
POST 1:
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-id="yes" data-problem_id="1" class="problem_vote">
      <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">YES</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-id="no" data-problem_id="2" class="problem_vote">
      <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">NO</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<br />------------------------
<br />
<br />POST 2:
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-id="yes" data-problem_id="1" class="problem_vote">
      <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">YES</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-id="no" data-problem_id="2" class="problem_vote">
      <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">NO</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```js
$('.problem_vote').on('click touchstart', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var problemVote = $('.problem_vote button');
  //disabled both button
  problemVote.prop('disabled', true);
  //add class with background color to the clicked element
  $('button', this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-id="yes" data-problem_id="1" class="problem_vote">
      <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">YES</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" data-id="no" data-problem_id="2" class="problem_vote">
      <button class="btn btn-no btn-vote">NO</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```